# Set a conditional breakpoint on XCode that watches a global variable

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, breakpoints

I'm trying to set a breakpoint that triggers anywhere within the scope of a viewController when a global variable takes certain value. So far I haven't found a way to do it because line breakpoints break at specific lines, symbolic breakpoints break at specific methods, and exception breakpoints break at, well, exceptions. But I just want the execution to stop at any point in the code without having to set a breakpoint at every line where I think it could happen.
Any ideas?

Comment: Create global getter and setter methods for the variable then you can break conditionally whenever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing a watchpoint, not a breakpoint. There is no user interface for setting a watchpoint on a global; you'll have to pause your running app and set it at the LLDB command-line:

```
(lldb) watch set variable myGlobalVariable
```

Comment: The LLDB tutorial tells you how to set a watchpoint that stops only if the variable in question takes on a specific value: http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Could you add a `didSet` observer to your variable and add a break-point inside that?

Simon